# Jtable which is set to listen cell selection events will not fire events

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selectionmodel

JTable which is set to listen cell selection events is not generating events when we select from the same row,, if i select other row other than the cell selected, Jtable fires events.

this is code... 
example when i select the cell "row0 col0", and then try to select any other cell in the same row, jtable will not fire any events,
in order to fire the events on "row 0 col 1" cell, i have to select any cell in row 2, and has to click on "row 0 col1" cell

```
public class test_jtable_event extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form test_jtable_event */
    public test_jtable_event() {
       initComponents();
    }



// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {"row 0 column1", "row 0column 2", "row 0 column 3", "row 0column4"},
            {"row 1 column 0", "row 1 column 2", "row 1 column 2", "row 1 column 2"},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jTable1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
        {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getSource());
                System.out.println(jTable1.getSelectedColumn());
                System.out.println(jTable1.getSelectedRow());
            }

        });
        jTable1.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(13, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(25, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test_jtable_event.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test_jtable_event.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test_jtable_event.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(test_jtable_event.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            new test_jtable_event().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 6):

row and column selection are controlled by different selection models:

- row: table.getSelectionModel()
- column: table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel()

you have to register your listener to both